# Translation of "count proportion" and "continuous proportion"

Tags: english-to-german, mathematics

I would like to know how to translate the terms *count proportion* and *continuous proportion* into German. I illustrate what I mean by these terms by means of two examples:

**Count proportion**
Suppose I toss a coin *b* times. The number of resulting heads is *a*. Then the quotient *a* /*b* is a count proportion.

**Continuous proportion**
Let *d* be a volume of beer and let *c* be the volume of alcohol that the beer contains. Then the quotient *c* /*d* is a continuous proportion (and in this case has its own [name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_by_volume)).

**Examples of real-life usage**
[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/239395/180214) and [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/29042/180214).

Comment: How about "[diskret (2)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/diskret)" vs. "kontinuierlich"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fitting translation for *proportion* is *Anteil* in this case, see e.g. [Linguee](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=proportion).

I don't think that there are established special terms for "count proportion" and "continuous proportion" in German.

Something that *is* used is the term *zahlenmäßiger Anteil*, in the sense of: you have a crate full of apples and oranges, and you can count fruits to get the *zahlenmäßiger Anteil* of apples, or you can weigh them or measure their volume to get the *Gewichtsanteil* or *Volumenanteil*. IMHO this might be a good fit for "count proportion", too.

A different way to approach this would be to look at the terms that are used for variables in general in statistics, which leads to *diskrete* vs. *stetige (or: kontinuierliche) Merkmale/Variablen:*

An explanation can be found e.g. [here](https://wissenschafts-thurm.de/grundlagen-der-statistik-worin-unterscheiden-sich-diskrete-und-stetige-merkmale-und-wann-sind-merkmale-haeufbar/) or in any basic statistics text.

Transfering this to proportions, the terms would translate to *diskreter Anteil* and *stetiger Anteil*. You can definitely use these and they make sense. Conceptually, the term *diskret* (discrete) is quite far away from *count* though.

Comment: I see this a lot and it bugs me but in my opinion **stetiger** Anteil is misleading and instead **kontinuierlicher** Anteil should be used.

Comment: @infinitezero: I see what you mean, I find "kontinierlich" to be the more intuitive term, too, but "stetig" seems to be the more commonly used one.

Answer (score 1):

The latter one is easier to answer and I would go with

> Kontinuierliches Verhältnis

> Sei *d* das Volumen eines Bieres und *c* das Volumen des im Bier enthaltenen Alkohols. Der Quotient *c/d* wird dann als **kontinuierliches Verhältnis** bezeichnet.

The first case is a bit more tricky. There is *Zahlenverhältnis* which literally means the relation of proportion between to numbers. However if you're counting something I'd go with *Zählverhältnis*. I didn't have any statistics class in German so I don't know if there's an established terminology. Possibly, the English expression is used verbatim in German.

> Sei *b* die Anzahl an Münzwürfen und *a* die dabei erhaltene Anzahl des Ereignisses "Kopf". Der Quotient *a/b* wird dann als Zählverhältnis bezeichnet.

The terms I'm familiar with are *diskrete* und *kontinuierliche* Wahrscheinlichkeitsverteilungen. However strictly speaking, this only works with proportions for large numbers.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, the word *Verhältnis* would do in both cases. I have never heard of special terms for this distinction, and frankly speaking, I doubt that it is used in English.

Comment: They are used, [see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239422/what-is-the-difference-between-count-proportions-and-continuous-proportions)

Comment: @infinitezero - I found that too. But even if it is used, I don't think it's well known; at least I didn't know about it and I've had a few statistics courses. Either way, I'd say the question is closable for requiring special knowledge of a subject other than German.

Comment: Verhältnis von Zählwerten, Verhaltnis kontinuierlicher Werte. However, the second example isn't actually a proportion. It is a fraction, i.e. "ein Anteil".